# Why is the model being all glitchy after i open it?

Tags: mesh, blend-files

This thing looks like it came straight out of hell, i don't know what is going on with Rain's model on the viewport, a glitchy black color appears on the mesh, and then when i try to orbit or move to another place on the 3D canvas, it looks like the black thing don't actually update, i mean, it moves along with the mesh, but it just stays in the same place related to my screen, as if i enabled some onion skin mode in blender's preferences

[image]

Comment: Either blenders broken or your gpu might be

Comment: I upvoted this question partially because of how funny it was, but to the point does this happen with any of your other models?

Comment: Is this the rendered view/shading view? If Yes, then this is a common problem for AMD/Radeon Graphic cards, and this can be avoided by checking *High Quality Normals* in RenderSettings>Performance